# JavaScript JSON to Map Object

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have a Map object in Java which I pass to JavaScript. The object looks like this

```
Map<String, String[][]>
```

Now I have a JSON object in Java which I pass to JavaScript and I need to convert this object in JavaScript so it will be the same kind as the one above.

This is the JSON i receive in JavaScript from Java:

```
{"Key":[["value1_1","value1_2","value1_3","value1_4","value1_5"],
["value2_1","value2_"],["value3_1","value3_","value3_3"],
["value4_1","value4_2","value4_3","value4_4","value4_5","value4_7"],
["value5_1"]]}
```

How should I construct the object on JavaScript side based on this object?

I need to access those values in JS, and later on modify them, etc.

Comment: `var object = JSON.parse(string)`

Comment: This is simple..var myObj = JSON.parse("Your Json String here"). It will make myObj as an array of objects

Comment: @gyre when I do `alert(object)` after that parsing, I see `[object Object]`. Later in the code I got following exception: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'K[G].push([J,D,L,H,F])')`. How can I display values from that object and later on add/remove some other values to it?